# Azure DevOps SHA Database Build fails w Error MSB4061 SqlModelResolutionTask could not be instantiated from Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Tasks.Sql.dll

Tags: azure-devops, database-project, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

My yaml file

```
trigger:
- main

steps:
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'VS Build on the Solution'
  inputs:
    solution: 'My.Database.sln'
    vsVersion: '17.0'
    platform: 'any cpu'
    configuration: 'Release'
```

Despite using a VSBuild step, it seems my Self-Hosted Agent is still trying to use the MSBuild within its own agent directory and is failing due to a missing dependency.

Error:

> ##[error]C:\agent\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Msbuild\lib\net46\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets(494,5): Error MSB4061: The "SqlModelResolutionTask" task could not be instantiated from "C:\agent\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Msbuild\lib\net46\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Tasks.Sql.dll"